# When did Jesus say something similar to this?

Tags: jesus

I dont have a bible, I do however listen to it while I drive long distances for work and I was trying to find the verse online where he said something along the lines of 'in those days, they will turn(or pray or call) to the lord not even washed from their own filth(or excrement)'.

I have been searching for hours and basically read all of Mathew and Luke on my phone in an attempt to find this but I cant. Its quiet infuriating because now im questioning if Jesus even said something similar to this or not.

Anyone recognize this qoute?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Please take the tour below.  I cannot recall a quote like this in the Gospels and could not find one either.  You will need to be more specific.

Comment: Are you thinking of 2 Peter 2 (21-22)? "For it had been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than after they have known it, to turn back from that holy commandment which was delivered to them. For, that of the true proverb has happened to them: The dog is returned to his vomit: and, The sow that was washed, to her wallowing in the mire."

Comment: The jist of the message is along those same lines but I could have sworn I heard it when Jesus was preaching about the condition of mankind during the end times. I'm going to be driving most of the day tommorow and if I make it through all of Mathew mark Luke and John and can't find it I will give up. It's just kinda maddening because I know I heard something along those lines.

Comment: It would have helped if you had a Bible version that the audio uses. I’m more curious why you’re looking for those verses but either way your question is not suited for this stack. I think Ruminator found the closest passage but it’s not in the NT

Comment: You can stop looking. Jesus never said any sentence along these lines. For Jesus' preaching on the end times, see Mt 24, Mk 13, and Lu 21. Of course, there are many smaller statements made through the gospels on the end times.

Comment: @Steve yesterday ok thx

Answer (score 2):

> Proverbs 30:11-14 New King James Version (NKJV)
>   11 There is a generation that curses its father,
>   And does not bless its mother.
>   12 There is a generation that is pure in its own eyes,
>   Yet is not washed from its filthiness.
>   13 There is a generation—oh, how lofty are their eyes!
>   And their eyelids are [a]lifted up.
>   14 There is a generation whose teeth are like swords,
>   And whose fangs are like knives,
>   To devour the poor from off the earth,
>   And the needy from among men.

Footnotes:
Proverbs 30:13 In arrogance
New King James Version (NKJV)
Scripture taken from the New King James Version®. Copyright © 1982 by Thomas Nelson. Used by permission. All rights reserved.

Sometime back I set this passage to music: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnaI9xQhmIW6gpgLYSv3g8I1-EHOUw